# I want to clean repeated lines in a HTML in R

Tags: html, url, process, expression, regular-language

I want clean repeated lines in a HTML in R and I have already ended to this. I only want to keep the country  names. What is the pattern?

```
mypage = readLines('http://www.worldslongestwebsite.com')
write(mypage, ("Raw Data.txt"))
mypage[1:1000]
grep('currentVisitor',mypage)
mypage[230:1000]
text<- toString(mypage[230:1000]) 
text
cleantext<- gsub(pattern="[\"\\<\\>\\=/,:-][0-9]*",replacement= " ",text)
```

result of a couple of lines

```
p class  c  Brazil  p   div                                                    div class  d   p class  a      p  p class  b     PM  p                        p class  c  Albania  p   div                                                    div class  d   p class  a      p  p class  b     PM  p                        p class  c  India  p   div                                                    div class  d   p class  a      p  p class  b     PM  p
```

Comment: Please show us your input which produces the result. And please format your code properly (4 indents at least).

Comment: It's been awhile since we've been able to bump this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1531971

Comment: Since you probably still want to do this even though all is (probably) lost, and the Elder Gods have been summoned: https://www.r-bloggers.com/string-functions-in-r/

Comment: What is "I have ended to this" ? and why not try harder showing us code and expected output?